# Hiding a div based on ASP checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to make an asp textbox/checkbox combo that will hide the textbox if the checkbox is checked but I cant get the jQuery/Javascript to work. I have tried many different solutions and havent gotten it to work so any help would be appreciated

ASP:

```
<div runat="server" id="editStartYear" class="productInfo">
    Edit Start Year:
    <asp:CheckBox ID="startDateCheckBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Unknown Start Date"/>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="startBox" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="150" placeholder="Start Year"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#searchIcon').hover(function () {
    $('#searchIcon').attr("src", "includes/images/searchIconHover.png");
}, function () {
    $('#searchIcon').attr("src", "includes/images/searchIcon.png");
});
$('#searchBox').focus(function () {
    $('#searchBox').attr("value", "");
});

$("#startDateCheckBox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#startBox").hide();
        } else {
            $("#startBox").show();
        }

});

});
```

Comment: This question could be better by adding the actual HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ClientIDMode="Static"` in the asp.net markup for the check box and the text box. Then the client side javascript can be used to address the check box. Right now you have it as a server side control.

```
$("#startDateCheckBox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $("#startBox").hide();
    } else {
        $("#startBox").show();
    }

});
```

Comment: how should I call the function? Should I just put it in the document.ready and get rid of the onclick? Right now with the onclick it is saying ReferenceError: hideStartDiv is not defined

Comment: Try having only this code in the document.ready. Comment everything else out. If it does not work, post your entire JavaScript

Comment: commenting it didn't solve the problem. I edited the question to have all the javascript including your suggested edits

Comment: Remove onclick="hideStartDiv()" from your asp.net markup

Comment: Put alert messages or console.log statements and see where the control reaches

Comment: I feel so stupid.. The build was cached so it wasnt even updated my javascript the entire time.